# Django - get an IP from which model inst was changed

Tags: python, django

In my models.py I have:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
            created = self.pk is None
            super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            print("Hello")
            pprint(kwargs)  
            user = kwargs.get('instance', None)
            ip = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
            if user:
                new_password = user.password
                try:
                    old_password = User.objects.get(pk=user.pk).password
                except User.DoesNotExist:
                    old_password = None
                if new_password != old_password:
                    AuditEntry.objects.create(action='Password has changed', ip="127.0.0.1", username=user.username)
```

It returns:

```
NameError at /user/user/3/password/
name 'request' is not defined
```

In this example - password reset. In views I use PasswordResetForm.

But I need to do it on almost any change in database.
I want to log an IP from which User model inst was changed. But I can't since request is not in models.
How can I get access to it?
Thanks.

Updated:
I've added a form:

```
class PasswordForm(PasswordResetForm):
    print("hello")
    def post(self, request):
        ip = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
        print("ip")
    def get(self, request):
        ip = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
        print("ip2")
```

I want it to trigger after every time password changes.
How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: By overriding the save method on the User model, this logic will be called everytime the user model is saved. That's probably not ideal as you might want to save the User as well in other cases e.g. updating name or email address. Why don't you add this logic to the form that is submitted when a password is updated?

Comment: Yes, I need to call this logic on almost any action, that changes user info. I wish I could add this to form, but in views.py I see no forms code, only PasswordResetForm import.

Comment: You could add a custom form that inherits from the PasswordResetForm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

request object has X-Forwarded-For header. It contains user's IP address.

Comment: But from where it could be accessed? In models.py there is no request. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Well, you can access it inside Middleware or View function, AdminModel. You can create a special Mixin that does the job for you. Also, you can pass IP to your save function, from view etc. To be more specific, we need context.

Comment: request object comes from a controller.